# Сессия, доступная на всех поддоменах

Tags: apache, .htaccess, сессия, php

Я знаю, что вопрос баянистый, но все же.
я пишу в php.ini:

```
suhosin.session.cryptua = Off 
suhosin.session.cryptdocroot = Off
session.cookie_domain = ".example.ru"
session.save_path = "/var/www/user/data/bin-tmp"
```

но сессия, созданная на code.example.ru не совпадает с сессией на example.ru/admin

Что же делать?

UPD:
код с code.example.ru:

```
<?
session_start();
if(isset($_GET['logout'])){
session_unset();
session_destroy();
}else{
$_SESSION['test'] = "ok";
}
print_r($_SESSION);
?>
```

код с example.ru:

```
print_r($_SESSION);
die();
```

вывод c code.ex...:

```
Array ( [test] => ok )
```

вывод с exampl...:

```
Array ( )
```

Answer (score 1):

В php.ini, если еще нет этих строк:

```
suhosin.cookie.cryptdocroot = Off
```

**Источник: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=43682**

Comment: ВАЖНО использовать php.ini

Comment: @Arc, разве?

Comment: Да, в данной задаче да.

Comment: Пардон, не видел этого условия. Исправил ответ.

Comment: Ничего не изменилось. Суть в том, чтобы в скриптах ничего не менять...

Comment: Прошу вас, внимательно прочитайте вопрос, особенно код в нем

Answer (score 0):

А разве через .htaccess это нельзя сделать вот так:?

```
php_value session.cookie_domain .site.ru
```

upd. проверил, у меня так работает.
Хотя Ваш код, тоже вроде правильный..

Comment: необходимо через php.ini. Кстати, при такой записи выдает ошибку